# How to split x-axis label names in a base R barplot from a dataframe exported from excel

Tags: r, excel, bar-chart, rename, x-axis

I have an excel document which looks like the one below:

[image]

When I created a barplot using the base R barplot function the x-axis labels did not fit in one line since the labels were long.

```
example <- read_excel("C:/path/to/document/example.xlsx")
View(example)

example <- example[order(example$Quantity, decreasing = TRUE),]

P <- barplot(height=example$Quantity, names=example$`Long  Name`, 
         col = c("red", "coral","orange", "yellow", "green", "aquamarine" , "cyan",     "magenta","violetred", "pink"),
         xlab = "Examples of long names",
         ylab = "Quantity", 
         ylim = c(0,60)
         )
text(P, example$Quantity+4,labels=as.character(example$Quantity)
)
```

[image]

I want to find a way split the labels so that it sits on different lines as I do not want to rotate the x-axis.

I tried splitting the lines by using \n and the names.arg argument:

```
P <- barplot(height=example$Quantity, names=example$`Long  Name`, 
             col = c("red", "coral","orange", "yellow", "green", "aquamarine" , "cyan",   "magenta","violetred", "pink"),
            xlab = "Examples of long names",
             ylab = "Quantity", 
             ylim = c(0,60),
             names.arg = c("Really \n really Long \n Name 10",
                       "Really \n really Long \n Name 3",
                       "Really \n really Long \n Name 2",
                       "Really \n really Long \n Name 5",
                       "Really \n really Long \n Name 1",
                       "Really \n really Long \n Name 7",
                       "Really \n really Long \n Name 6",
                       "Really \n really Long \n Name 9",
                       "Really \n really Long \n Name 4",
                       "Really \n really Long \n Name 8"
         ))
text(P, example$Quantity+4,labels=as.character(example$Quantity)
)
```

But the label ends up being written over the graph.

[image]

Is there a way to either move all 3 lines down below the graph/ shift the graph up  or is there a completely different way to split the lines? Ideally without having to use names.arg as it's a bit tedious to do it this way

Comment: You could try with `pos=1` in your `text` call?

Comment: did you try setting your plot margins ? You could make the margin below the graph larger, so it would have more space to print your labels

Comment: I've tried both suggestions but still not able to solve this problem